# Does Firebase Storage rules get the same request object as Firestore rules does?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have some Firestore rules that look like this:

**firestore.rules**

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /adac/{documentID} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth.token.admin == true;
    }
  }
}
```

Does the same work for storage rules?

**storage.rules**

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.admin == true;  // <---- CAN I DO THIS ?
    }
  }
}
```

I mean, will my Storage get the same request object that my Firestore does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, custom claims are available in security rules for both Firestore and Storage.

Please refer to the API documentation for both [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth) and [Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage#auth).